# Inject a service for angular unit testing with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have my angular **app A** with a **module M** and and a **service S**. Module **M** is injected to **A**:

```
angular.module('A', ['M'])
    .service('S', function () {
        //some service functionality
    });
```

**M** has an own **service MS** that has a dependency on service **S**:

```
angular.module('M', [])
    .service('MS', ['S', function (S) {
        //stuff goes here
    }]);
```

Now i want to test **MS** with karma and jasmine. I inject **M** with

```
beforeEach(module('M'));
```

And then i grab **MS** with:

```
var MS;

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    MS = $injector.get("MS");
}));
```

And thats the point where I'm already running into an injector error... What's wrong, what am I missing here? Thank you! :)

Comment: Don't you need to `beforeEach(module('A'));` too?

Comment: Yeah I thought so as well but when I try that i get an module error in return.